# Docker image for windows 64bit

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I got my Docker up and running on windows,

Now I want to make a container from my application that needs to be installed on a windows server 64bit.

Is there a clean image of windows server that I can use?

I looked in dockerhub and saw some images that I can use like [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockcross/windows-x64/).

But I want to make sure I'm doing it right, Can I work with this image to install my app?

Comment: You can 2 things:
- you can push your image to remote repository and pull it on your destination machine
- you can export the image you want, and the import on the destination machine

Comment: maybe I didn't explain myself clearly , before creating the image locally when I will declare "FROM" in my dockerfile is there a clean (official )windows image I can use?

Comment: I think that this might be helpful: https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/

Comment: Here is detailed walk through how it works. https://github.com/artisticcheese/artisticcheesecontainer/wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question that you are asking here is, what Windows Server base image should you use to create your new image from? This really depends on the requirements of the application that you are running in the container, but Microsoft has official base images for both Windows Server Core and Nano Server available on Docker Hub, the links are as follows:

Server Core base image - https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/

Nano Server base image - https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/nanoserver/

Please also note that Microsoft have other images available which are based on the above images, such as one which includes ASP.Net Core ( https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/ ) which may make a better base image for you, it really depends on the requirements of your application.

Finally - the full list of Microsoft provided images can be found at https://hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/

I hope the above is helpful.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for,I foubd those images yesterday but forgot to update with an answer. Can I connect to CMD in the nano image ?

Comment: Yes, you can.  If you want to create an interactive nanoserver container running the cmd process simply use the command 'docker run -it microsoft/nanoserver cmd'

If you have a container that is already running and you want to connect to CMD in the container then run the command 'docker exec -it [CONTAINER ID] cmd'

Hope that helps.